# Как найти строку в массиве байт?

Tags: c++, linux

Нужно найти строку в массиве байт. Т е из файла читается его содержимое в массив байт, затем в этом массиве ищется строка. Обычный find() или strstr() не помогут, т к файл бинарный -> т е могут встретиться символы переноса строки, нуль-байты и т д. Узнал про `memmem`, но для меня вариант оказался нерабочий - возвращает **SIGSEGV**:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    struct stat buf;
    stat("binary", &buf);
    const unsigned int fsize = buf.st_size;
    ifstream bins;
    bins.open("binary", ios::in|ios::binary);
    char *cbuf = new char[fsize];
    char ch;
    unsigned int k = 0;
    while(bins.get(ch)) {
        cbuf[k] = ch;
        k++;
    }
    bins.close();
    const void *pos = memmem(cbuf, fsize, "/system", 7);
    const int *ipos = (int *)pos;
    delete[] cbuf;
    printf("%d", *ipos);
    return 0;
}
```

```
 ~/work $ g++ -g main.cpp
 ~/work $ ./a.out
Segmentation fault
 ~/work $ gdb ./a.out
gdb > r
Starting program: /home/me/work/a.out

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000005555555dd0 in main () at main.cpp:24
24          printf("%d", *ipos);
```

А мне нужно найти строку в массиве байт таким образом, чтобы получить себе позицию начала строки в массиве. Т е, если первый символ искомого слова является 439м байтом, то должно вернуть число 439.

Comment: Посмотрите в сторону [std::search](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/search). Примерно [так](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3e28cac3d5cf02b1). `вариант оказался нерабочий - возвращает SIGSEGV` Немудрено, ведь после освобождения буфера `delete[] cbuf;` указатель `ipos` указывает на фрагмент освобождённое памяти. Его разыменование вызывает неопределённое поведение. Также нарушено [правило строгих псевдонимов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/503265) (`*ipos`), и требования по выравниванию (`(int *)pos`).

Comment: спасибо за причину ошибку `SIGSEGV`, теперь все работает) UPD: мне выводит число, большее размеру буфера...

Comment: `мне выводит число, большее размеру буфера`. Если вы всего лишь перенесли освобождение буфера в конец программы, то тоже ожидаемо. `pos` хранит указатель на начало последовательности символов `"/system"` внутри `cbuf`. Вы интерпретировали `sizeof(int)` (обычно `4`) байт этой последовательности как значение типа `int`. Т.е. ваша программа выводит значение байтов `"/sys"`, как `int`. [Вывелось `1937339183`](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/528356bfd3b00ea2)?

Comment: UPD: решил проблему

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вычитайте указатели на `char *` чтобы вычислить смещение.

```
const char *pos = static_cast<const char *>(memmem(cbuf, fsize, "/system", 7));
if (pos == nullptr) {
    printf("Not found\n");
} else {
    const ptrdiff_t ipos = pos - cbuf;
    printf("%td", ipos);
}
delete[] cbuf;
```

Comment: После освобождения буфера `delete[] cbuf;` указатели `pos` и `cbuf` становится невалидным. Попытки чтения и манипуляций над прочитанными значениями вызывают неопределённое поведение. И неожиданные вещи [происходят](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33374483).

Comment: @wololo, спасибо. Поправил.

Answer (score 0):

```
const char *pos = static_cast<const char*>(memmem(cbuf, fsize, "/system", 7));
const ptrdiff_t ipos = pos - cbuf;
if (ipos < 0 || ipos > fsize) {
printf("Can't find!\n");
} else {
printf("%d\n", ipos);
}
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Функция `memmem` в случае успеха возвращает указатель на элемент массива `cbuf`, но в случае неудачи возвращает нулевой указатель. Нельзя из нулевого указателя вычитать указатель на объект. Это вызывает неопределённое поведение (см.: [expr.add/5](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.add#5), [арифметика указателей](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/477309)). Чем вам не угодил способ [предложенный](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1424246) @StanislavVolodarskiy?

Comment: `%d` не совместим с `ptrdiff_t`. Используйте `%td`.